# Camel Kafka Connector (jms/amq source connector) - Message acknowledgement mode not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, apache-camel-k

I am trying to pull messages from AMQ broker and move them to Kafka topic using [Camel-sjms2-kafka-connector](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/connectors/camel-sjms2-kafka-source-connector.html). It all works good in happy path scenarios. But, if I manufacture a runtime error eg. forcing kafka connect user not to have write permissions on the kafka topic its publishing to, I notice the smjs2 connector pulling the message from AMQ and failing to publish the same to kafka as expected. However, the message on AMQ gets acknowledged as soon as its polled and hence its lost.

Do camel kafka connectors support message acks? I tried with setting ack mode to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and session as transacted etc, but it doesn't work.

How can I ensure, there are no message drops using camel kafka connectors. I am fine with messages getting redelivered.